# How to use str.find() function in python

Tags: python

What I am trying to achieve is I want to allow user to input only any website from `google.com` and `goo.gl` only. To do this, my sample code in python console is like this:

[image: Testing find() function in console]

The returned result `false` is correct because `url` does meets criteria containing `goo.gl`. I went on testing with few more options url like `https://google.gl/LoZXyE`, the `find()` function return `true` because it does not meet criteria containing words 'google.com' or 'goo.gl'.

My problem is that if I assign variable url the value like below which I expected it to return `true` from `find()` function above because it does not contain word 'goo.gl' at all, yet it return `false`.

[image: Test Find function in console]

What is wrong happening? How can I validate url like the case above result like expected?

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. They are unreadable, unsearchable, and cannot be copied/pasted.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I tried post the actual text but website won't allow posting short url, so I decide to print screen instead, thanks.

Comment: Your second url **does** contain the string `'goo.gl'`.

Comment: Forget `str.find` and use [the right tool for the job](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That line

```
url = 'https://goo.glAB/LoZXyE'
```

does indeed contain 'goo.gl', but you do not want it because it is immediately followed by `AB` in the url, which changes the top-level domain.

One way around that is to not search for `goo.gl` but for `//goo.gl/`. That works in the examples you gave, and prevents both following and preceding characters that change the top-level domain. That makes the line

```
url.find('//google.com/') == -1 and url.find('//goo.gl/') == -1
```

Remember that the line above works only in the interactive console. To use it in a program put it in an `if` line or an expression, such as

```
if url.find('//google.com/') == -1 and url.find('//goo.gl/') == -1:
```

or

```
expr = url.find('//google.com/') == -1 and url.find('//goo.gl/') == -1
```

or (more like your interactive line)

```
print(url.find('//google.com/') == -1 and url.find('//goo.gl/') == -1)
```

Comment: It's better to use [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) for this sort of thing and explicitly check the domain component (i.e. the `netloc` property).

Comment: @RoryDaulton, Thanks very much for your helpful and descriptive answer, it works find as expected. Yes, in deed, I use `if, else` already in my real code, I validate url using Flask-Validator built-in `[validator.url()]` that help me with validating url, the problem only I allow my user only input any url from google.com and goog.gl. And your answer did really help, very much thanks :)

Comment: @ekhumoro, very much thanks for an alternative, I will have a look and try it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
url.find('google.com/') == -1 and url.find('goo.gl/') == -1:
  ...
```

Comment: That is not valid python code: it will raise a `SyntaxError`.